# SQL: Calculate the interval a value falls into

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a column like this:

```
column1   
      4
     12
     23
      6
     14
     35
```

I want to create another column next to it that will show the range that the value from `column1` falls into, like this:

```
column1        column2  
      4            0-5
     23          21-25 
      6           6-10
     14          11-15
     33          31-35
```

It seems to be a simple ranking task, but I'm having trouble making it work. I am pretty new to SQL and probably am missing something basic. So maybe just point a direction for me to go from where I am now, because I am lost.

So far I have looked into using `CASE` (with no success) and `RANK()`. The latter doesn't work for me at all, as in it's not even highlighted as a keyword (I am using Sybase Interactive SQL v12.0.1). Although it looks to me that `RANK()` is not the way to go even if it worked, since I need my values ranked in precise ranges (0 to 35 with step 5).

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Don't have values overlap, like 0-5 and 5-10.

Comment: Which group does 10 belong to? 5-10 or 10-15?

Comment: Salman, it doesn't matter that much, I think. Give me a minute to edit the question.

Comment: So zero is a super special case (because all your ranges start with 1 or 6 as the last digit)?

Comment: Salman, yeah, I guess. I definitely need to begin with zero, because there are values like `0.18` in the `column1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to group values inside `0-5` (special case), `6-10`, `11-15` and so on, just use the following query (written for SQL Server but illustrates the idea):

```
SELECT num, CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN num <= 5 THEN 0 ELSE FLOOR((num - 1) / 5) * 5 + 1 END,
    '-',
    CASE WHEN num <= 5 THEN 5 ELSE FLOOR((num - 1) / 5) * 5 + 5 END
)
FROM ...
```

[Tests on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=584bb476c985a745f50d065c0c65b628)

Replace `FLOOR(x / y)` with integer division operator if available.
Replace `CONCAT` with appropriate string concatenation operator or function.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot for your help and for guiding me!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
select col1,
       concat( floor(col1 / 5) * 5, '-', 5 + floor(col1 / 5) * 5)
```

You can also use the '||' operator:

```
select col1,
       floor(col1 / 5) * 5 || '-' || (5 + floor(col1 / 5) * 5))
```

Or whatever method your database uses for string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

or 
`concat(column1-(column1%5), "-", column1-(column1%5)+5)`

Answer (score 0):

select col1,
       concat( floor(col1 / 5) * 5, '-', 5 + floor(col1 / 5) * 5)